# Add a simple UIView as header of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, header, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `UICollectionView`. I would like to add a header. My header would only be a `UILabel`. I've :

1) selected "Section Header" as a Collection View accessory in the IB.

2) created a Collection Reusable View in the IB, on the side, declared as `collectionViewHeader`.

3) added those lines :

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

            return collectionViewHeader;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

But they are never called.

Do I have to create a class just for that label in order to use

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header"];
```

?

Why isn't it as simple as the `UITableView` where you just drag and drop whatever header you want ?! Things are so complicated with `UICollectionView`...

Answer (score 64):

In swift like below

Register Header View

```
collectionView.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView")
```

In `UICollectionViewDataSource`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    headerView.frame.size.height = 100

    return headerView
}
```

Important is that you are supply the flow layout with the header size

```
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100)
```

Otherwise the data source method will not get called

Comment: Should Header View be UICollectionReusableView?

Comment: viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind this is in UICollectionViewDataSource not UICollectionViewDelegate

Comment: instead of headerReferenceSize can also be implemented this method func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize

Answer (score 25):

If you don't set the header view in storyboard, you will have to register nib.

Example in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.collectionView registerClass:NSStringFromClass([YourOwnSubClass class]) forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderViewIdentifier"];
}
```

Anyway, you can also subclass UICollectionReusableView.

```
@interface YourOwnSubClass : UICollectionReusableView
```

then call delegate in your class example:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    YourOwnSubClass *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:
                                         UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
    [self updateSectionHeader:headerView forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return headerView;
}

- (void)updateSectionHeader:(UICollectionReusableView *)header forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"header #%i", indexPath.row];
    header.label.text = text;
}
```

And don't forget to set header size in collection view or in flow layout so header view will be visible.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Unfortunately the collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath is not called. And do you know how to add a nib to YourOwnSubClass ?

Comment: then perhaps you forgot to set your self as delegate?
What do you mean? add a nib as a subview? or initialize YourOwnSubClass from nib?

Comment: Delegate is set, everything else works fine :/ I mean initialize YourOwnSubClass from nib, as it is a UICollectionReusableView.

Comment: YourOwnSubClass *sub = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XibOrNibName" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

Comment: It is not a Delegate, but a DataSource method.

Comment: You need to set flowLayout.headerReferenceSize in order to get the method to be called.

Comment: can header view be the type of UIStackView or UIView ? 
I am getting error if I used the headerView is the type of UIView. 

'Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'dequeueReusableSupplementaryView'

Answer (score 4):

None of above works if you forgot to enable accessory in your XIB file, don't forget to activate your desired section!

[image]