# Adding UIButton to UICollectionView header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an array of `UIButtons` that I would like to add to a `UICollectionViewController` header.

Doing it via Interface Builder is easy, but I can't seem to find any resources for doing this in code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just add the buttons as subview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731318/add-a-simple-uiview-as-header-of-uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

Implement the method `-collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` method in the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol.

That method returns a `UICollectionReusableView`, which is really just a view.  As the previous poster said, simply create that an object of that type in the method, and use it as a normal UIView, adding buttons as subviews.

If you have a header in a XIB/storyboard that you want to add buttons to, just dequeue the correct view from the UICollectionView with a reuseIdentifer, then add them as subviews to that dequeued UICollectionReusableView.