# how to make scrollview grow based on collection view number of rows in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

i have a scrollview which has a picture, text, button, label and then a collectionView whose number of rows is dynamic in nature. Its like collectionview will grow in height and hence the scrollview should assume collectionView height as well as other elements height to get a smooth scroll. How to achieve this using auto Layout in ios?

So my doubt is how to make a dynamic scrollview height based on a growing colelctionview or tableview height.

Comment: Collection view implements UIScrollView by itself. The content size will adapt to the content you will provide

Comment: Are you using `AutoLayout`?

Comment: Do you want to increase the content size ?

Comment: my viewcontroller has a headerview, image, text(long) followed by collection view which grows i want my entire content to be scrollable.. not just the collectionview. Yes using autolayout.

Comment: see the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the height of `CollectionView` Height Constraint , connect Height contains to your  `ViewController` and than .

[how to connect constraint to outlet ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22110084/4466607)

```
let height = self.collectionView.contentSize.height;
self.heightConstraints = height;

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(widht:self.scrollView.frame.size.width,height:height)
```

Answer (score 2):

These methods didn't work for me. Try,

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.heightCollectionViewConstraint.constant = self.collectionViews.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FOr Swift 4.2

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let heightFilterCOll = self.filterCollectionView.contentSize.height
    self.filterCOllectionViewCOnstraintHeight.constant = heightFilterCOll

    self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.ScrollView.frame.size.width,height:heightFilterCOll + 77)
}
```